# adding object collision in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a mario, platformer type game, and from following a tutorial, they've done the collision like this, but im wondering if there is a simpler way to it since I want to have collision on more than one object.

1. Side collision

   ```
   if (Player.Right > Block.Left && Player.Left < Block.Right - Player.Width && Player.Bottom < Block.Bottom && Player.Bottom > Block.Top)
   {
       right = false;
   }
   if (Player.Left < Block.Right && Player.Right > Block.Left + Player.Width && Player.Bottom < Block.Bottom && Player.Bottom > Block.Top)
   {
       left = false;
   }
   ```
2. Top collision

   ```
   if (Player.Left + Player.Width > Block.Left && Player.Left + Player.Width < Block.Left + Block.Width + Player.Width && Player.Top + Player.Height >= Block.Top && Player.Top < Block.Top)
   {
       //Player.Top = Screen.Height - Block.Height - Player.Height;
       //force = 0;
       //if (jump == true)
       //{
       //    Player.Image = Image.FromFile("mario_stand.png");
       //}
       jump = false;
       force = 0;
       Player.Top = Block.Location.Y - Player.Height;
   }
   ```
3. Head collision

   ```
   if (Player.Left + Player.Width > Block.Left && Player.Left + Player.Width < Block.Left + Block.Width + Player.Width && Player.Top - Block.Bottom <= 10 && Player.Top - Block.Top  > -10)
   {
       force = -1;
   }
   ```

Comment: There are ways to optimize the code (for instance, putting the objects in a X-sorted list, so you have to check collisions only on a given range), but I don't believe there is a "simpler" algorithm

Comment: You might have a lot better answers on GameDev.SE. SO is really for helping with code issues, not dealing with algorithms. But this is really easy to Google anyway - use spatial partitioning and a for cycle.

Comment: Is there a way I could move this question? I'm quite new to this site.